# Angular 6 - Specify path for lazy loaded chunks

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl

I have a main module with submodules, originally I wanted to make that modules eager loaded, so what I did:

**1st Attempt - Eager loading**

```
import {DashboardModule} from './module/dashboard/dashboard.module';
export const _dashboardModule = () => DashboardModule;
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: _dashboardModule
            }
        ]
    }                
];
```

It worked just fine for me until I start building prod build with aot compilation. In that moment I get into issue which is mentioned here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4192

**2nd Attempt - Lazy loading**

Based on ticket I linked above I start using string paths for modules e.g.

```
loadChildren: './path/to/module/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
```

which generate separate bundle for each module. For build I used angular-cli command

```
ng build --output-path=../my/ouput/path --prod --aot --output-hashing none --vendor-chunk
```

Because my application is part of huge existing  application I can't use generated `index.html` but I use `.ftl` file where I specify from where all scripts should be loaded like this:

```
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>

    <script src="<@versionedUri src="${base}/path/to/file/runtime.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<@versionedUri src="${base}/path/to/file/polyfills.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<@versionedUri src="${base}/path/to/file/styles.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<@versionedUri src="${base}/path/to/file/vendor.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<@versionedUri src="${base}/path/to/file/main.js"/>"></script>
</body>
```

And that's an issue if you try to lazy load because output files of my build is in different folder then my `.ftl` file which I use instead of `index.html` problem is that when you open application in browser it try to load chunks from same folder where `.ftl` is located and they doesn't exist there.

**What my questions are:**

- Is there a way to specify path for chunks files?
- Or is there some other way to eager load module without importing child routes and use them like: `children: dashboardRoutes`

Comment: When you use lazy load is important not import the loaded module, its better load children throught path string

Answer (score 5):

The path where lazy-loaded chunks (and all other `.js` scripts) are generated is designated in the angular.json file, @ (projects: <*projectName*>: architect: options:) outputPath: <*your-output-path*> ...

I'm having trouble myself, getting the Angular app to look for the chunk at this location, it seems to be looking for it at the root (baseUrl).

I'm in a similar situation as OP, embedded the Angular app in a .NET MVC5 application, so rather than using the Angular-generated index.html, the file "serving" the app is the MVC Home/Index view. My `Index.cshtml` file looks very similar to OP's `.ftl` file... my quandary is how to tell the Angular app to look for the chunk at the outputPath location?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you able to find out the solution?

Comment: Adding deployUrl in angular.json file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar situation, and what helped was adding deploy url to my angular.json. The comment by Hermant Jain helped. I am just adding this answer to specify where to add this setting in angular.json.

Follow this path in angular.json:

Projects -> Your Project -> Architect -> Build -> Options-> deployUrl

The other way around without specifying this is to pass this as a parameter as follows:

```
    ng build --watch --deploy-url /dist/
```

This way, my chunks are loading from myWeb/dist/

Comment: Using `deployUrl` fix it in case the deployment URL has no virtual directory/folder aka `somesite.xyz/theApp` if the folder `theApp` isn't used it will work.
I need to cover both cases and I can't find a way to get to work. If I use `base href` It will fix the folder case but break others!